# How to reference a method parameter from lambda in C#

Tags: c#, lambda, reflection

Given this lambda

```cs
public static Expression<Func<int, int>> Add(int add)
{
    return x => x + add;
}
```

it creates the following debug output:

```
.Lambda #Lambda1<System.Func`2[System.Int32,System.Int32]>(System.Int32 $x) {
    $x + .Constant<ConsoleAppExpressionTest.Program+<>c__DisplayClass1_0>(ConsoleAppExpressionTest.Program+<>c__DisplayClass1_0).add
}
```

The debug view shows that the field `add` is addressed within a constant.

How to create the same lambda dynamically?

What i've tried:

```cs
public static Expression<Func<int, int>> Add(int add)
{
    var x = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "x");
    var expr = Expression.Add(x, Expression.Field(Expression.Constant(null), "add"));

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<int, int>>(expr, x);
}
```

leads into a `System.ArgumentException: 'Instance field 'add' is not defined for type 'System.Object''`.

While using the parameter directly as constant would just create a copy of the value: `Expression.Constant(add)`

Comment: You are getting slightly confused by the `Field` you see the compiler create. However, that is only because the compiler creates a closure for you. Here you can see what the compiler turns your original code into: https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA+ABATARgLABQGADAAQY4B0AMgJYB2AjpQKIIAOsAzl7RPVwDchQhgDM5HEnJZSAYVIBvQqVXkJFaW04wefegB4MAVgMMALgBpSFgHy3SAQQAmzgBQXSAQ1cBKFWrKBGoh5ADspAikALwOUQDU3q7CwWoAvoRpQA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick to this is to use simple `Expression.Constant(add)` or `Expression.Constant(add, typeof(int))` (it is a good idea to express the type explicitly, especially if the value could be `null`).

---

As for using the field approach: you cannot, and neither can the regular compiler in your first version. What the compiler does is generate a *closure*, and use *that* i.e.

```cs
var obj = new SomeGeneratedClosureType();
obj.add = add; // and now *all* mentions of "add" use obj.add instead
```

and uses *that object* as the constant in:

```cs
var expr = Expression.Add(x, Expression.Field(Expression.Constant(obj), "add"));
```

This `SomeGeneratedClosureType` is the `ConsoleAppExpressionTest.Program+<>c__DisplayClass1_0` in your question code.

However, it is *more efficient and more direct* **not** to do this, and just use the value directly. The compiler can't do this because it needs to maintain certain guarantees about how the value behaves, that aren't possible if you just use the value directly.

Comment: while `Expression.Constant(add)` will deliver a different result to what i need, this still answers my question with the information about the closure type. thank you!

Comment: @cyptus note: in most cases, an anonymous type will suffice to mimic a closure/capture generated type, i.e. `var obj = new { add }`

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want :

```
    public static Expression<Func<int, int>> Add(int add)
    {

        var x = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "x");
        var addExpression = Expression.Constant(add);
        var expr = Expression.Add(x, addExpression);

        return Expression.Lambda<Func<int, int>>(expr, x);
    }
```

Comment: as i told in my question, the static value of `Expression.Constant(add)` is not what i need in this context. I want to achive a reference, like the example in the debug view did.